# No results when searching for terms in Office files

Tags: 2010, search

I'm trying to make my SharePoint search service index files through a BCS connector.

I implemented a StreamAccessor in the BDC model and deployed the solution. A full crawl then indicates success. However, searching for terms contained in indexed Office documents (.docx, .pptx) doesn't work, even with simple, small files - search results are empty. Also, if I search on the file *name* it works, but corresponding search result doesn't include any snippet of the file contents.

Oddly enough, plain text (.txt) files do work. Indexed Office files from a regular Sharepoint content source (document library) also work.

Here's an excerpt from my BDC model :

```
        <Method Name="GetAttachmentStream">
          <Parameters>
            <Parameter Name="myId" Direction="In">
              <TypeDescriptor Name="myIdTypeDescriptor" TypeName="System.Int32" IsCollection="false" IdentifierName="MyId" /></Parameter>
            <Parameter Name="stream" Direction="Return">
              <TypeDescriptor Name="streamTypeDescriptor" TypeName="System.IO.Stream" /></Parameter>
          </Parameters>
          <MethodInstances>
            <MethodInstance Name="GetAttachmentStreamInstance" Type="StreamAccessor" ReturnParameterName="stream" ReturnTypeDescriptorPath="streamTypeDescriptor">
              <Properties>
                <Property Name="MimeTypeField" Type="System.String">MimeType</Property>
                <Property Name="FileNameField" Type="System.String">FileName</Property>
              </Properties>
            </MethodInstance>
          </MethodInstances></Method>
```

The MimeType field in my items is populated with for instance : `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document` for a .docx, `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation` for a .pptx.

Any help would be much appreciated.

**[Edit]**

I changed the MIME types to match what appears under OfficeServer\Search\Setup\Filters in the Sharepoint server's registry, namely `application/vnd.ms-word.document.12` and `application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.12`. It still doesn't work.

Also tried :

```
            <Property Name="Extension" Type="System.String">Extension</Property>
            <Property Name="ContentType" Type="System.String">MimeType</Property>

            <Property Name="MIMETypeField" Type="System.String">MimeType</Property>
            <Property Name="FileNameField" Type="System.String">FileName</Property>
```

But I get a "dot notation refers to a node that doesn't exist" exception on the very "MimeType" field name that has been generating no crawl exception when used with `MIMETypeField` property until now.

I really can't get my head around this.

Comment: It sounds like the file type is not being sent to the right iFilter.

Comment: Sure, but why ?

Comment: I'll try an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect your Mime types. Isn't "12" Office 2007? I saw this answer to a similar question in the forums from Scot Hillier:

1. Define the MimeTypeField in both the Finder and SpecificFinder if you also use the UseClientCachingForSearch property.
2. The MimeType for WORD documents is:
   application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document

OH, and it appears some folks are having success with Extension instead of mime type.
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/944e6878-a7f0-4c0e-98b7-a7fb9faeef1b/bcs-connector-and-mimetypefield

HTH
M